# LINQ join tables and count groups

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write a linq query that performs this SQL for my Entity Framework connection:

```
SELECT 
    l.Site_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    vw_Subnet s
INNER JOIN 
    vw_Lab_Space l ON l.Lab_Space_id = s.Lab_Space_Id
WHERE 
    s.Lab_Space_Id IS NOT NULL 
    AND s.MM_Space_Id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    l.Site_Name
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC
```

but I can't figure out the right syntax.  Without the `WHERE` clause I had tried this, but it's not actually doing the `GROUP BY` part like all the examples I've seen imply it should be:

```
from l in db.vw_Lab_Space.AsNoTracking()
join s in db.vw_Subnet.AsNoTracking()
  on l.Lab_Space_Id equals s.Lab_Space_Id into joined
select new SiteCount {
    Site = l.Site_Name,
    Count = joined.Count()
};
```

I'm getting back a `SiteCount` with repetitive Site values.

Comment: You need to add a `groupby` to match the query, have you tried doing that?

Comment: No.  Could you help me with the syntax please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: Yes, but that's grouping when just using a single table.  I'm trying to group against the joined output, and that it confusing me.  That's why I'm asking for help here to understand the syntax I should be using.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the syntax doesn't change. Anywa you're only grouping by a single column, go try it out - that's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to write the specification about what you want to achieve, but it seems to be the following.

You have a sequence of vwLabSpaces, where every vwLabSpace has a LabSpaceId and a SiteName.

You also have a sequence of vwSubnets where every vwSubnet has a LabSpaceId

You want to join these two sequences on common LabSpaceId. Then you want to group the joined elements into groups of element sthat have the same value for SiteName (so every element in one group has the same SiteName)

The end result should be a list of the common siteNames of each group and the number of elements in each groups.

In baby steps:

```
// your two sequences:
IQueryable<VwLabSpace> vwLabSpaces = myDbContext.VwLabSpaces;
IQueryable<VwSubNet> vwSubNets = myDbContext.VwSubNext;

// join on common LabSpaceId
var joinedItems = vwLabSpaces.Join(vwSubNets, // join the two sequences
    vwLabSpace => vwLabSpace.LabSpaceId,      // from every vwLabSpace take the LabSpaceId
    vwSubNet => vwSubNet.LabSpaceId,          // from every vwSubNet take the LabSpaceId
    (vwLabSpace, vwSubNet => new              // when they match make a new
    {                                         // joined object containing
        VwLabSpace = vwLabSpace,              // both matching objects
        VwSubNet = vwSubNet,
    });

    // make groups of joinedItems that have same SiteName
    var groupsWithSameSiteName = joinedItems
        .GroupBy(joinedItem => joinedItem.VwLabSpace.SiteName);

    // finally: get the common SiteName (= Key) and count the elements of each group
    var result = groupsWithSameSiteName
        .Select(group => new        // from every group make one new object
        {                           // with two properties:
            SiteName = group.Key,   // the common SiteName of all elements in the group
            Count = group.Count(),  // and the number of elements in the group
        });
```

TODO: if desired make one big LINQ statement. Because of lazy execution this won't make a difference.

As you only use the SiteName of each joined item, you don't have to combine the complete joining objects:

```
// join on common LabSpaceId
var joinedItems = vwLabSpaces.Join(vwSubNets, // join the two sequences
    vwLabSpace => vwLabSpace.LabSpaceId,      // from every vwLabSpace take the LabSpaceId
    vwSubNet => vwSubNet.LabSpaceId,          // from every vwSubNet take the LabSpaceId
    (vwLabSpace, vwSubNet) =>                 // when they match
        vwLabSpace.SiteName);                 // keep the SiteName
```

Comment: Thank you, that's incredibly help to understand what's going on!

Comment: I forgot one piece.  Instead of `COUNT(*)` I actually need `COUNT(DISTINCT(s.Lab_Space_Id))`.